# Injecting singleton into prototype in spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

What will be the behavior of class loading of injecting singleton into prototype bean ?

I have tried other way round injecting prototype in singleton and resolving the issue using lookup method.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, if you use a BeanFactory or not. A BeanFactory can load classes lazily.

### Without BeanFactory

If from the start until the end of a Spring-Context the concrete Implementation of the Singleton and the Prototype is known, they are load at least if the start-method of the Context is called. The default class-initializations of a Class in java is done by the used ClassLoader.

That means, before the beans are autowirable,

1. implements-interfaces and extends-classes are iniaitlized.
2. the static-class-scope is called,
3. the static fields are initialized and set.

After that, the Context starts using the `start`-method.

1. The Default-Constructor of the Singleton is called.
2. The {} scope is called.
3. All @Autowired fields are set.
4. If the Singleton extends the SmartSingletonInitializer, its inherited methods are called.
5. The @PostConstruct-method is called.

Then if a prototype Bean is required (either by `context.getBean` or by direct `@Autowired`, the Prototype's.

1. The Default-Constructor of the Singleton is called.
2. The {} scope is called.
3. All @Autowired fields are set.
4. If the Prototype extends the SmartSingletonInitializer, its inherited methods are called.
5. The @PostConstruct-method is called.
6. The Prototype-Instance is injected.

### With BeanFactory

It might behave different because the Prototype bean can return a instance of a Bean that not yet has been load from the corresponding classloader. If so, the prototype bean is load in this order in-time:

1. implements-interfaces and extends-classes are iniaitlized.
2. the static-class-scope is called,
3. the static fields are initialized and set.
4. The Default-Constructor of the Singleton is called.
5. The {} scope is called.
6. All @Autowired fields are set.
7. If the Prototype extends the SmartSingletonInitializer, its inherited methods are called.
8. The @PostConstruct-method is called.
9. The Prototype-Instance is injected.

Comment: my ask was to how many instance will get created on call of getBean multiple times

Comment: @AvinashJethy A Prototype bean is always created if getBean is called. A Singleton bean is never created by getBean.